# get_schema multiple primary keys

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, schema

I am trying the following:

```
from pandas.io.sql import get_schema
tbl_schema = get_schema(contracts, 'my_contracts', keys=['country', 'contract_id'], con=db_engine)
```

I am getting this

```
ArgumentError: Element ['country', 'contract_id'] is not a string name or column element
```

which seems likely coming from this:

```
def _to_schema_column_or_string(element):
    if hasattr(element, '__clause_element__'):
        element = element.__clause_element__()
    if not isinstance(element, util.string_types + (ColumnElement, )):
        msg = "Element %r is not a string name or column element"
        raise exc.ArgumentError(msg % element)
    return element
```

I am not sure I understand how the multiple primary keys should be formatted to be parsed properly. I don't really understand this: [`util.string_types + (ColumnElement, )`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/type_basics.html#sql-standard-types) I was hoping I could just point to the frame columns without having to define the whole SQLAlchemy schema.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in `get_schema`. It works in the older version, but not with the new implementation using sqlalchemy engines apparantly. Open an issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10385

Comment: How are you using the output of `get_schema`? Depending on that, maybe you, for now as a workaround, can only supply one column as key and then edit the output to add the second as well. But certainly not ideal ..

Comment: @joris: yes, the hack could work. And thanks for opening the issue ticket on github.